# AWS CDK, typescript - Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

I have this code generated by cdk cli(typecript-language):

```
import { Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as appsync from '@aws-cdk/aws-appsync';

export class BookStoreGraphqlApiStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const api = new appsync.GraphqlApi(this, 'MyApi', {
            name: 'my-book-api',
            schema: appsync.Schema.fromAsset('graphql/schema.graphql')
        });
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'.
  Type 'BookStoreGraphqlApiStack' is missing the following properties from type 'Construct': onValidate, onPrepare, onSynthesize
```

My package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.10",
    "@types/node": "10.17.27",
    "aws-cdk": "2.2.0",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-appsync": "^1.136.0",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.2.0",
    "constructs": "^10.0.12",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
  }
```

Node version: v16.13.0

aws-cdk version: 2.2.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are mixing dependencies from CDK V1 and V2, which are incompatible.  See the [migration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/migrating-v2.html).

---

*[2023 Note]: The AppSync L2 constructs are now stable and moved to `aws-cdk-lib`. The `aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha` package is no longer needed.*

---

To get a valid V2 setup, change the AppSync package to `import * as appsync from '@aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha'`.  In V2, alpha
APIs have separate packages, stable ones are in a common `aws-cdk-lib`.  AppSync's L2 constructs are in the alpha category.

Here is an overview of import patterns for both CDK versions:

```js
// V2
import { Construct } from 'constructs'; // construct is in a separate package
import { Stack, StackProps, aws_s3 as s3 } from 'aws-cdk-lib'; // common package for stable construct
import * as appsync from '@aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha'  // alpha constructs in separate packages

// V1 - separate packages core and for each service
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as appsync from '@aws-cdk/aws-appsync';
```

This table shows where to find the dependencies for each CDK version:

| Package | CDK Version | Constructs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `aws-cdk-lib` | v2 | L1 (`CfnSomething`) constructs and stable [L2/L3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) constructs |
| `@aws-cdk/aws-something-alpha` | v2 | experimental L2/L3 consturcts |
| `@aws-cdk/aws-something` | v1 | all |

Comment: I had the same problem, I was following the CDK V1 example (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/serverless_example.html) but I had already installed CDK v2, so I needed to follow the CDK V2 example (
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/serverless_example.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, the docs still haven't been updated. Thanks Amazon  This kinda mess gives us job security I guess.

Comment: You can find the documentation here: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/ and 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-construct-library.html

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a known problem with aws-cdk, since v2 isn't properly migrated, the solution is:

```
npm un -g aws-cdk
```

```
npm i -g aws-cdk@1.136.0
```